# cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_<capture_instance> return unexpected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, cdc

I have strange problem, I turned on CDC on my SQL Server table.
When I use `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_<capture_instance>` function I get latest state of row with performed operation but with no understandable operation value for me. Issue is that `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_<capture_instance>` returns the following result:

| __$start_lsn | __$seqval | __$operation | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x00007772412111 | 0x000077724AAA1244 | 1 | 123 | 5 |
| 0x00007772412111 | 0x000077724AAA1244 | 2 | 123 | 6 |

there are only 1 and 2 operations (delete and insert) for specific row, but
`cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_<capture_instance>` returns the following result:

| __$start_lsn | __$operation | __$update_mask | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x00007772412111 | 4 | NULL | 123 | 6 |

I have completely no idea why `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_<capture_instance>` returns **4** as value, instead of **2** because it was the last operation returned by `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_<capture_instance>`.

I was expecting such result:

| __$start_lsn | __$operation | __$update_mask | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x00007772412111 | 2 | NULL | 123 | 6 |

Do you have any idea why is there such result?

Comment: Possibly the modification was an `UPDATE` which changed the primary key (which is essentially a delete and insert)?

Comment: I'm more confused as to why the update mask in the net changes call is null. But as to your question as to why the operation is update rather than delete, let's think of what the typical use case for CDC is. You have a secondary data source that is in sync with this database as of a previous time. It includes ID 123 (not hypothetical - its presence as a delete in the call to get all changes says so). If the call to get net changes said "insert the row with ID 123", you'd get a PK violation when syncing the secondary source. It *has* to be an update.

Comment: @BenThul, thanks a lot for making me realised. Regarding update mask, I use 'all' parameter(Returns the LSN of the final change to the row and the operation needed to apply the row in the metadata columns __$start_lsn and __$operation. The column __$update_mask is always NULL)